# WebServiceIOException when testing a web service client using MockWebServiceServer

Tags: java, spring-boot, mocking, junit5, spring-test

I'm trying to write an integration test and part of that test requires mocking a REST call and also a SOAP call. The REST part works fine, I'm able to mock that. The SOAP call is proving difficult to mock. I get an WebServiceIOException.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:561)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:378)
    at ca.nbc.payment.pmt_commons_mcp_connector.service.OdsPreferencesConnector.getPreferences(OdsPreferencesConnector.java:18)
    at ca.nbc.payment.pmt_commons_mcp_connector.service.McpConnectorMessageService.processGetCustomerMessage(McpConnectorMessageService.java:46)
    at ca.nbc.payment.pmt_commons_mcp_connector.stream.McpConnectorStreamListener.handleCustomerManagementMessageRetrieve(McpConnectorStreamListener.java:29)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(StreamListenerMessageHandler.java:55)
```

Here is my client class, the class that extends WebServiceGatewaySupport

```
public class OdsPreferencesConnector extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

  @Value("${ods.url}")
  private String odsUrl;

  public String getPreferences(String memberIdNo) {
    GetPreferencesResponse getPreferencesResponse = (GetPreferencesResponse) getTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(odsUrl, getGetPreferencesRequest(memberIdNo));

    if (!getPreferencesResponse.getServiceResponse().getPreferenceList().getPreference().isEmpty()) {
      return getPreferencesResponse.getServiceResponse().getPreferenceList().getPreference().get(0).getPrefValue();
    }

    return null;
  }

  private WebServiceTemplate getTemplate() {
    WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();

    Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    jaxb2Marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(GetPreferencesRequest.class, GetPreferencesResponse.class);
    webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller);
    webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller);

    return webServiceTemplate;
  }

  private GetPreferencesRequest getGetPreferencesRequest(String memberIdNo) {
    GetPreferencesRequest getPreferencesRequest = new GetPreferencesRequest();

    getPreferencesRequest.setServiceRequest(new GetPreferencesRequestType());
    getPreferencesRequest.getServiceRequest().setPartyNumber(new PartyNumberType());
    getPreferencesRequest.getServiceRequest().getPartyNumber().setMemberIdNo(memberIdNo);

    return getPreferencesRequest;
  }

}
```

Here is my test class

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("integration-tests")
class IntegrationTest {

  @Autowired
  private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @Autowired
  private MessageCollector messageCollector;

  @Autowired
  private McpConnectorStream mcpConnectorStream;

  @Autowired
  private static OdsPreferencesConnector odsPreferencesConnector;

  private static MockWebServiceServer mockServer;

  private static WireMockServer wireMockServer;

  @BeforeAll
  public static void setup() {
    wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(options().bindAddress("127.0.0.1").port(14000));
    wireMockServer.start();

    odsPreferencesConnector = new OdsPreferencesConnector();

    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(odsPreferencesConnector, "odsUrl", "http://localhost:12000/ws");

    mockServer = MockWebServiceServer.createServer(odsPreferencesConnector);
  }

  @AfterAll
  public static void afterAll() {
    wireMockServer.stop();
  }

  @Test
  void handleCustomerManagementMessageGet() throws Exception {
    PaymentCommonsCustomer receivedMessage = TestObjectBuilder.createPaymentCommonsCustomerMessage();
    GetIndividualBaseResponse getIndividualBaseResponse = TestObjectBuilder.createIndividualBaseResponse();

    // Mock MCP REST call
    wireMockServer.stubFor(WireMock.get("/individuals/" + receivedMessage.getBncId() + "/base")
        .willReturn(aResponse()
            .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .withBody(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(getIndividualBaseResponse))));

    // Mock ODS SOAP call
    Source requestPayload = new StringSource(TestObjectBuilder.createGetPreferencesRequestXML());
    Source responsePayload = new StringSource(TestObjectBuilder.createGetPreferencesResponseXML());
    mockServer.expect(payload(requestPayload)).andRespond(withPayload(responsePayload));

    sendMessage(receivedMessage, StreamAction.ACTION_GET);

    Message<String> sentMessageJson = (Message<String>) messageCollector.forChannel(mcpConnectorStream.outboundCustomerApi()).poll();
    assertNotNull(sentMessageJson);

    PaymentCommonsCustomer sentMessage = objectMapper.readValue(sentMessageJson.getPayload(), PaymentCommonsCustomer.class);

    assertEquals(receivedMessage.getMessageId(), sentMessage.getMessageId());
    assertEquals(receivedMessage.getTransactionDate(), sentMessage.getTransactionDate());
    assertEquals(receivedMessage.getLastPublishedDate(), sentMessage.getLastPublishedDate());
  }

  private void sendMessage(PaymentCommonsCustomer message, String action) throws Exception {
    mcpConnectorStream.inboundMcpConnector().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(message)).setHeader("action", action).build());
  }

}
```

If the SOAP web service is up, then my unit test works fine. Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong? I'm using Java 11 and JUnit 5.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently. The problem is your `WebServiceTemplate`, you are creating a new instance each time you call your service.

Instead of that, try to either inject a `WebServiceTemplate` or use the one `WebServiceGatewaySupport.getWebServiceTemplate()` provides by default and do not manipulate anything from the service template when you call your service.

One thing that `MockWebServiceServer.createServer(client)` does, it's to take your service template and set a `MockWebServiceMessageSender` as a message sender which is the one you need to avoid the actual http call, in your code the mock is never been called because the creation of a new service template instance everytime. Finally, you won't need the `WireMockServer`